# list packages available for download/install in Julia version 1.0

Tags: julia

In version 0.4 there was Pkg.available() which I used to look at what packages were available for download/install. How do you do this in v1.0?

Yes, I have read the documentation and searched extensively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are keeping your package repository in a standard location you can use

```
using Pkg
Pkg.update()
reg = "~/.julia/registries/General/Registry.toml"
regdict = Pkg.TOML.parsefile(reg)
pkg_list = getindex.(values(regdict["packages"]), "name")
```

If you use a non-standard location of the Registry.toml file then you can see it e.g. when you run `Pkg.update()` command or get it using `Pkg.Types.registries()` (the directory where this file lies should be the first entry in the list).

Finally you can fetch Registry.toml from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General GitHub repository.

**EDIT:**

Using standard functions you could do it as follows

```
using Pkg
reg = joinpath(Pkg.Types.registries()[1], "Registry.toml")
regdict = Pkg.Types.read_registry(reg)
pkg_list = getindex.(values(regdict["packages"]), "name")
```

Comment: @scls: it seems that you have omitted a `.` after `getindex`. Running `getindex.(values(regdict["packages"]), "name")` works fine under Julia 1.0.3.

Comment: I just copy/paste (with dot)... but my mistake was I was using Julia 0.7 (not 1.0)

Comment: Thank you.  This was what I was looking for.  However, it seems surprising that you have to do all this just to browse the packages available.

Comment: I guess (but I am not a core developer) that the issue is that you can install packages from many places - not necessarily the official registry only.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use tab-completion in the `Pkg` REPL mode.

For example:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add JS[TAB]
JSON          JSONWebTokens  JSON2          JSExpr         JSONSchema
```

(Where `[TAB]` represents a key-press, not literal characters)